# Obtain attachment content from OWA through Outlook web add-in

Tags: outlook-web-addins, outlook-web-app

I'm trying to get the content of an attachment from a mail item using the Office.context.mailbox.item.getAttachmentsAsync() API call from my add-in, however I'm running into some unexpected results...

In my add-in, I get a list of all the attachments in the mail item:

```
var listOfAttachments = item.attachments;
if (listOfAttachments.length > 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < listOfAttachments.length; i++) {
        _att = listOfAttachments[i];
        console.log("Attachment name: " + _att.name);
        console.log("Attachment type: " + _att.attachmentType);
        console.log("Attachment content type: " + _att.contentType);
        console.log("Attachment ID: " + _att.id);
        console.log("string length: " + _att.id.length);
     }
```

This works fine... However, I realised that the attachment ID, is longer than 100 characters (180 characters actually). And in the API reference of the getAttachmentContentAsync() function, the first parameter is the attachment ID, which the reference states: "The identifier of the attachment you want to get. The maximum length of the string is 100 characters."

So based on that, I think I have identified the problem. The issue now is, how to solve it. What attachment ID is this API expecting?

Thanks!

Update: This is the code that I'm using to retrieve the attachment content:

```
var options = { asyncContext: { type: _att.attachmentType } };
item.getAttachmentContentAsync(_att.id, options, function (result) {
            if (result.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
                console.log("Call returned success!");
                var AttachmentContent = result.value; // Get the attachment content
                if (AttachmentContent.format == Office.MailboxEnums.AttachmentContentFormat.Base64) {
                    // handle file attachment
                    console.log("Base64 String: " + AttachmentContent.content);
                }
                else if (result.format == Office.MailboxEnums.AttachmentContentFormat.Eml) {
                    // handle item attachment
                }
                else {
                    // handle cloud attachment  
                }
            } else {
                var err = result.error;
                console.log("Call failed: " + err.name + ": " + err.message);
            }
        });
```

The error that I'm getting is this: 
Unable to get property 'status' of undefined or null reference

For purpose of troubleshooting, I printed out the attachment id: 
AAMkADU4OTU2Mjg4LThiNzktNDY0Yi1hZmE4LWFmMjAzZjczYjIxOQBGAAAAAADiRE+1naePQ7MPCJEcJqgqBwCgpNXsitDwTY/mc0w2Y/zOAAAAAAEMAACgpNXsitDwTY/mc0w2Y/zOAAARXFqBAAABEgAQAN0M5JhRvPxIoP5KYNYRk54=

I read from a few pages that different API expects slightly different format of the attachment id. So I'm not sure if this is the source of the issue...

Comment: I believe you meant using the getAttachmentContentAsync method? This is the method that takes in an attachment Id, getAttachmentsAsync doesn't. Also, we don't enforce a limit of 100 characters, we shall update the document to reflect that. What exact errors are you seeing when you call getAttachmentContentAsync with the attachment id?

Comment: Hi Outlook Add-ins Team, yes I meant getAttachmentContentAsync. I have updated my original post. Also, I posted the code that I wrote to call the function, please have a look at it to see if I'm using it correctly. Thanks!

Comment: Your code seems to work fine on our end without any errors. We tried it on a read email(which is where you are trying it I believe) and get the expected result back. Could you debug and check what is the value of result Object in your callback? Also, is this happening for all emails that have an attachment? Does this even happen on a draft email that has an attachment?

Comment: Also note that this API is still in preview and not yet fully released to all clients/customers for consumption. It is also possible that you happen to be on a release channel that does not have this feature enabled yet.

Comment: Hi Add-ins Team, the platform I'm currently testing on is https://outlook.office.com/owa/ is this feature enabled on it?

Comment: Also, how do I check the value of result object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The getAttachmentContent API is not yet implemented for OWA. For the null result object - This is a known issue. It has been put on our backlog. We unfortunately have no timelines to share at this point.

Also, to answer you second question, since you are testing OWA, you can simply go to developer tools and place a breakpoint there to test the add-ins and use the console window to check variables data in them.

Comment: Ok, so I found another way to do it - via the Outlook REST API. (e.g. var getMessageUrl = Office.context.mailbox.restUrl + '/v2.0/me/messages/' + itemId + '/attachments/' + _attachmentID). Could you tell me, internally, what's the difference between using REST API and the getAttachmentContentAsync()? Do both still talk to the Exchange server, or is the getAttachmentContentAsync() getting the attachment content locally? Thanks!

Comment: For OWA, getAttachmentContent is not yet implemented, so it's early to discuss internals in details. Having said that, OWA will likely to make a call to Exchange Server. For your solution, please consider what you are going to do with the attachment content. If you are going to send the attachment to your backend, you can make the rest call directly from your backend. The idea is this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/get-attachments-of-an-outlook-item, but it's preferable to use REST like you wrote (instead of EWS)